# Android - Firebase Ui get data from other table?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Hello everyone I need to get user_fname from other table reference with uid

[image]

[image]

Below this my code 
I'm use IndexedQuery and not clear from tutorial and sample code [Firebase Ui](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md)

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("mainboard");
mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.mainboard_alllist);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
mOption = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Mainboard>().
            setIndexedQuery(mRef , mReference  ,Mainboard.class)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .build();

mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Mainboard, MainboardViewHolder>(mOption) {
    @Override
    public MainboardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mainboard_list , parent , false);
        return new MainboardViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(MainboardViewHolder holder, int postion, Mainboard mainboard) {
        String mb_id = mainboard.mb_id;
        mRef.child( mb_id + "/mb_auther").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String mb_author = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                mReference.child(mb_author + "/user_fname").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String user_fname = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                        Log.e("user_fname" , dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                        holder.setAuthor(user_fname);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Easily you can do this by first getting the id from one path and by using that id you can get the values from that path

Comment: In your code you are using MyRef to get the value and it is pointing to the `mainboard` not to `mainboard/id/rp_author/` do check that

Comment: my code use mainboard sir  not Report but it same concept

Comment: Can you please paste your filebase structure here. A screenShort of your firebase values

Comment: i add also sir or you need jsondata also

Comment: Check my edited code below in place of id you need to paste any of the mainboard ID. example id is -KrHOUwrsBbXHvUaOTIu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight method

1.First get the `mb_auther` value using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` listener

2.Then using that `mb_auther` value get the `user_fname`

```
  mRef.child("id/mb_auther").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { //Your case id is -KrHOUwrsBbXHvUaOTIu
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String mb_auther = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            mReference.child(mb_auther + "/user_fname").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String user_fname = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()
                    Log.e("user_fname", user_fname);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Basically in firebase datas are not stored in table structure. It is stored in KeyValue pair as JSON value

Comment: @C.Junior  So you need to know the path to any variable to access your data. From the figure your path is `report/-Kr4SZv2bxisQsYWESOw/rp_author`

Comment: can solve all error but on result author post get user_id not a user_fname

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157434/discussion-between-c-junior-and-sushin-pv).

Comment: @C.Junior check my updated code and move all your operations on the data only after getting the data from firebase on inner listener.
because retrieving data from firebase is depending on the internet speed.

Comment: Oh Awsome i forget it it work now but get more problem ok on your answer mean id/mb_auther i call mb_id (from model) + "/mb_auther" it ok can get all user_fname now and i scrolldown my list get crash and null string same line String mb_author = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(); plz check my code again i will update it

Comment: @C.Junior Ok. do update that. If you have more problem discuss it on chat.

Comment: Ok im done i can solve it i find on my database not get mb_auther it crash thx a lot